# I am trying to write a js function that returns the index of a an array of strings, in case the string "keys" is in the array

Tags: javascript

My function should return the index where "keys" is located, in case of success, or -1 if "keys" is not in the array.  But I get -1, I don´t see where is my mistake.

```
const findMyKeys = arr => { 
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === 'keys') {
    return i;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
}

const randomStuff = ['credit card', 'screwdriver', 'keys']
```

Comment: Just a side note. In ES6, I usually wrap my function arguments in parentheses like `const findMyKeys = (arr) => ..`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `findIndex`.

```js
const findMyKeys = arr => arr.findIndex(item => item === 'keys');

console.log(findMyKeys(['credit card', 'hello world', 'keys']));
console.log(findMyKeys(['credit card', 'hello world']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only return -1 if the `for loop` finishes and did not find the string:

```js
const findMyKeys = (arr) => { 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 'keys') {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

const randomStuff = ['credit card', 'screwdriver', 'keys']
console.log(findMyKeys(randomStuff))
randomStuff.pop();
console.log(findMyKeys(randomStuff))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method for this:

```js
const findMyKeys = arr => {
  return arr.indexOf("keys")
}

const randomStuff = ['credit card', 'screwdriver', 'keys']

const result = findMyKeys(randomStuff)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try arrays findIndex method. 
['a', 'b', 'c'].findIndex((item, index) => item === 'c')

The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating that no element passed the test.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex